# How to show similar word from two columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataframe

```
Id   Column_1               Column_2
1    United States          United Tractor
2    Love of Fair           Tales of Grim
3    Hotel Marriot Jakarta  Marriot Hotel Jakarta
```

Here's my expected output

```
Id   Column_1               Column_2               Word
1    United States          United Tractor         united
2    Love of Fair           Tales of Grim          of
3    Hotel Marriot Jakarta  Marriot Hotel Jakarta  hotel marriot
```

Data:

```
{'Id': [1, 2, 3],
 'Column_1': ['United States', 'Love of Fair', 'Hotel Marriot Jakarta'],
 'Column_2': ['United Tractor', 'Tales of Grim', 'Marriot Hotel Jakarta']}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `set.intersection` in a list comprehension:

```
df['Word'] = [' '.join(set(x.lower().split()) & set(y.lower().split())) for x,y in zip(df['Column_1'], df['Column_2'])]
```

Another option is to `stack` the columns; then use `groupby.apply` on a lambda where we do `set.intersection`:

```
df['Word'] = (df[['Column_1', 'Column_2']].stack().str.lower().str.split()
              .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(set(x.iat[0]) & set(x.iat[1]))))
```

Output:

```
   Id               Column_1                Column_2                   Word
0   1          United States          United Tractor                 united
1   2           Love of Fair           Tales of Grim                     of
2   3  Hotel Marriot Jakarta  Marriot Hotel Jakarta   hotel marriot jakarta
```

Answer (score 1):

quite similar but a bit different solution:

```
df['Word'] = (df[['Column_1', 'Column_2']].
              applymap(lambda x: set(x.lower().split())).
              apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.Column_1 & x.Column_2),1))
>>> df
'''
   Id               Column_1               Column_2                   Word
0   1          United States         United Tractor                 united
1   2           Love of Fair          Tales of Grim                     of
2   3  Hotel Marriot Jakarta  Marriot Hotel Jakarta  hotel marriot jakarta
```